# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 trying to run server in node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, server, nodemon

I have write code for connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connection successfull!');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('Connection failed!');
})
```

after run server occurred this error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, try it Give permission use sudo

```
sudo pkill node
```